# VBA to get the href value

Tags: vba, web, web-scraping, href, extract

I am writing macro to extract the href value from a website, example here is to extract the value: '/listedco/listconews/SEHK/2015/0429/LTN201504291355_C.pdf' from the html code below. The href is one of the attributes of the html tag 'a', I have add the code getElementbyTagName'a' but it did not work, my question is how to extract that href value to column L. Anyone could help? Thanks in advance!

```
  <a id="ctl00_gvMain_ctl03_hlTitle" class="news" href="/listedco/listconews/SEHK/2015/0429/LTN201504291355_C.pdf" target="_blank">二零一四年年報</a>
```

```
Sub Download_From_HKEX()
    Dim internetdata As Object
    Dim div_result As Object
    Dim header_links As Object
    Dim link As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim i As Object
    Dim ieDoc As Object
    Dim selectItems As Variant
    Dim h As Variant

    Dim LocalFileName As String
    Dim B As Boolean
    Dim ErrorText As String
    Dim x As Variant

    'Key Ratios
    For x = 1 To 1579
        Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
        IE.Visible = True
        URL = "http://www.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/advancedsearch/search_active_main_c.aspx"
        IE.navigate URL
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = 4
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        Call IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_txt_stock_code").setAttribute("value", Worksheets("Stocks").Cells(x, 1).Value)

        Set selectItems = IE.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$sel_tier_1")
        For Each i In selectItems
            i.Value = "4"
            i.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Next i

        Set selectItems = IE.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$sel_tier_2")
        For Each i In selectItems
            i.Value = "159"
            i.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Next i

        Set selectItems = IE.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$sel_DateOfReleaseFrom_d")
        For Each i In selectItems
            i.Value = "01"
            i.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Next i

        Set selectItems = IE.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$sel_DateOfReleaseFrom_m")
        For Each i In selectItems
            i.Value = "04"
            i.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Next i

        Set selectItems = IE.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$sel_DateOfReleaseFrom_y")
        For Each i In selectItems
            i.Value = "1999"
            i.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Next i

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Set ieDoc = IE.Document
        With ieDoc.forms(0)
            Call IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("document.forms[0].submit()", "JavaScript")
            .submit
        End With
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

        'Start here to extract the href value.
        Set internetdata = IE.Document
        Set div_result = internetdata.getElementById("ctl00_gvMain_ctl03_hlTitle")
        Set header_links = div_result.getElementsByTagName("a")
        For Each h In header_links
            Set link = h.ChildNodes.Item(0)
            Worksheets("Stocks").Cells(Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 12) = link.href
        Next
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anyone could help？

Comment: What is the problem you have encountered? It's not clear from your question. Edit your question to elaborate.

Comment: `div_result.getElementsByClassName("a")` >> `div_result.getElementsByTagName("a")`

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, thanks for your answer but sorry it is just a typo. I did tried getElementsByTagName, as well as getElementsByClassName("news"), they did not work, a solution may be get the attribute "href" after getting the TagName"a", since the "href" is one of the attributes of tag "a". But I don't know the code to get attributes, could you help?

Comment: Your anchor element with target href has `id="ctl00_gvMain_ctl03_hlTitle`, so you can retrirve url `IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_gvMain_ctl03_hlTitle").href` or simply `IE.document.ctl00_gvMain_ctl03_hlTitle.href`. Also try to retrieve the data you need via XHR instead of IE.

Comment: Hi omegastripes, sorry, I tested but it did not work, maybe the changes I made is not the same as what you proposed. Would you please advise the code after your changes? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
For Each h In header_links
     Worksheets("Stocks").Cells(Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 12) = h.href
Next
```

EDIT: The `id` attribute is supposed to be unique in the document: there should only be a single element with any given id. So

```
IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_gvMain_ctl03_hlTitle").href
```

should work.

Comment: @Tim Williams, Hi Tim, your code works for extracting all the href links on the website but what I want to extract is only those with `id="ctl00_gvMain_ctl03_hlTitle"`, the href attribute is one of those attributes in the tag <a>, I think something like getAttribute would work but I don't know the coding for that, could you help again? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Tim Hi Tim, I am currently using your firs answer which is `h.href` method, it works perfectly. But I did not test your updated answer. However, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
WB.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_gvMain_ctl04_hlTitle").GetAttribute("href").ToString
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS selector to get the element then access its `href` attribute.

```
#ctl00_gvMain_ctl03_hlTitle
```

The above is element with `id ctl00_gvMain_ctl03_hlTitle`. `"#"` means id.

```
Debug.Print IE.document.querySelector("#ctl00_gvMain_ctl03_hlTitle").href
```