# Get href value from speicific class in vba

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Iwant to get the href link from the following code:

```
<div class="border-content">
        <div class="main-address">

            <h2 class="address">
                <a href="/Propiedades/Detalles/7717095--Departamento-tipo-casa-de-1-Dormitorio-en-Venta-en-Capital-Federal?ViewNameResult=VistaResultados" title="Marcos paz 2500. Villa Devoto - Capital Federal">Marcos paz 2500<span></span></a>
            </h2>
```

i tried using getelementsbytagname("a") but i don't know how to do that for the specific class "address". Any ideas?

Comment: Did you even search for this? If you take your title and put it in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Get+href+value+from+speicific+class+in+vba), many results pop up.  Even one on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677931/vba-to-get-the-href-value). Do none of these help?  Please let us know what you've tried, what you've searched for, and how your efforts are/aren't working.

Comment: the codes i saw where looking all "a" in the webpage so i could not use it. I ended up using the outerHTML property by creating an array spliting it by chr(34) and i got it out. not the best way but it works

Comment: How are you doing this? With plain string manipulations? Regular Expressions? Have you tried some XPath?

Comment: Try this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476502/getelementsbyclassname-open-ie-vs-msxml2-methods Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kilian, here's how i handle everything. Quite complicated but it worked, although it takes for ever as i have plenty of nested loops:

```
Sub Propiedades()

'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
'to refer to the HTML document returned
Dim html As HTMLDocument
'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate "http://www.argenprop.com/Departamentos-tipo-casa-Venta-Almagro-Belgrano-Capital-Federal/piQ86000KpsQ115000KmQ2KrbQ1KpQ1KprQ2KpaQ135Kaf_816Kaf_100000001KvnQVistaResultadosKaf_500000001Kaf_801KvncQVistaGrillaKaf_800000002Kaf_800000005Kaf_800000010Kaf_800000041Kaf_800000011Kaf_800000020Kaf_800000030Kaf_800000035Kaf_800000039Kaf_900000001Kaf_900000002Kaf_900000006Kaf_900000008Kaf_900000009Kaf_900000007Kaf_900000010Kaf_900000033Kaf_900000034Kaf_900000036Kaf_900000038Kaf_900000037Kaf_900000035Kaf_900000039Kaf_900000041Kaf_900000042Kaf_900000043"
'Wait until IE is done loading page
Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to argenprop ..."
DoEvents
Loop
'show text of HTML document returned
Set html = ie.Document
'close down IE and reset status bar
Set ie = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""
'clear old data out and put titles in
Sheets(2).Select
Cells.ClearContents
'put heading across the top of row 3
Range("A3").Value = "Direccion"
Range("B3").Value = "Mts cuadrados"
Range("C3").Value = "Antiguedad"
Range("D3").Value = "Precio"
Range("E3").Value = "Dormitorios"
Range("F3").Value = "Descripcion"
Range("G3").Value = "Link"


Dim PropertyList As IHTMLElement
Dim Properties As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Property As IHTMLElement
Dim RowNumber As Long
Dim PropertyFields As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim PropertyField As IHTMLElement
Dim PropertyFieldLinks As IHTMLElementCollection

Dim caracteristicasfields As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim caract As IHTMLElement
Dim caracteristicas As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim caractfield As IHTMLElement

Set PropertyList = html.getElementById("resultadoBusqueda")

Set Properties = PropertyList.Children

RowNumber = 4

For Each Property In Properties

   If Property.className = "box-avisos-listado clearfix" Then

    Set PropertiesFields = Property.all
        For Each PropertyField In PropertiesFields
            Fede = PropertyField.className
            If PropertyField.className Like "avisoitem*" Then

                Set caracteristicas = PropertyField.Children

                For Each caract In caracteristicas
                    f = caract.className
                    If f = "border-content" Then
                        Set caracteristicasfields = caract.all

                        For Each caractfield In caracteristicasfields

                            test1 = caractfield.className
                            u = caractfield.innerText
                            If caractfield.className <> "" Then
                                Select Case caractfield.className

                                Case Is = "address"
                                    Cells(RowNumber, "A") = caractfield.innerText
                                    marray = Split(caractfield.outerHTML, Chr(34))
                                   Cells(RowNumber, "G") = "www.argenprop.com" & marray(5)
                                Case Is = "list-price"
                                    Cells(RowNumber, "D") = caractfield.innerText
                                Case Is = "subtitle"
                                    Cells(RowNumber, "F") = caractfield.innerText 'descripcion

                                'Case is ="datoscomunes"
                                    'Set myelements = caractfield.all

                                Case Is = "datocomun-valor-abbr"

                                    Select Case counter
                                    Case Is = 0
                                        Cells(RowNumber, "B") = caractfield.innerText 'square mts
                                        counter = counter + 1
                                    Case Is = 1
                                        Cells(RowNumber, "E") = caractfield.innerText 'DORMITORIOS
                                        counter = counter + 1
                                    Case Is = 2
                                        Cells(RowNumber, "C") = caractfield.innerText ' antiguedad
                                        counter = 0 ' reset counter
                                        Set caracteristicasfields = Nothing
                                        Exit For 'salgo del loop en caractfield
                                    End Select 'cierro el select del counter

                                End Select 'cierro el select de caractfield.classname
                            End If ' cierro If caractfield.className <> "" Then
                        Next caractfield

                    End If ' cierro el border content
                    If caract = "border-content" Then Exit For 'salgo del loop dentro de aviso item (caract)

                Next caract
            RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
            End If ' If PropertyField.className Like "avisoitem*"
        Next PropertyField   'para ir al siguiente aviso

   End If


Next Property

Set html = Nothing

MsgBox "done!"
End Sub
```