# How do I let my VBA web scraping code keeps up with the new window?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I open a new link in my VBA code and it only opens in a new window so the code can't follow along to the new window.

I'm stumped this is my code.

```
<div class="table-r">
  <table class="table-c">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="bg">
        <td class=" np">    <a title="comm" href="logcomm-e.asp?id=3" rel="history">3</a> </td>
        <td class=" np">    <a title="comm" href="logcomm-e.asp?id=2" rel="history">2</a> </td>
        <td class=" np">    <a title="comm" href="logcomm-e.asp?id=1" rel="history">1</a> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
Sub IEScrape()
  Dim IE As Object
  Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    With IE
         .Visible = True
         .Navigate "inhouse web site"

         While IE.readyState <> 4
             DoEvents
         Wend

         .document.querySelector("a[href*='logcomm-e.asp?id=']").Click

         While IE.readyState <> 4
             DoEvents
         Wend

    End With

  Set IE = Nothing
  ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

I expect when I run a get element and print it to a cell it's from the new href link. I can't go straight to the link because there's a new link every day and the href get's updated. by using the querySelector it clicks on the latest entry. Currently it's at 3 tomorrow 4 and so on.

Comment: As a work around - can you get the href address of the new window and open it through the `IE.Navigate newAddress`? It should work and I guess it would be reliable, if you manage the closing correctly.

Comment: I can't since it gets the latest link and there's a new one every day today is #3 tomorrow is #4 and so on thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I do not mean "hardcoding it", I was meaning reading the `href` from the opened page and then going there. See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677931/vba-to-get-the-href-value

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you could provide code that I could try then it would make sense I don't think the link you provided relates to mine.

Comment: Try to get the `href` of `.document.querySelector("a[href*='logcomm-e.asp?id=']").` With something like `someString = .document.querySelector("a[href*='logcomm-e.asp?id=']").href` (did not test). And then write `IE.navigate someString`.

Comment: oh okay I've tried something similar earlier but it didn't work but now it works thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I have added the last comment to the answer. Feel free to edit it to the code that works :)

Comment: yeah I just did this `.Navigate (.document.querySelector("a[href*='logcomm-e.asp?id=']").href)` basically your suggestion thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the `.href` property of the `querySelector` and then navigating to it, should work:

```
With IE
     Dim hrefString as String
     hrefString = .document.querySelector("a[href*='logcomm-e.asp?id=']").href
     .Navigate = hrefString
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly faster would be to use class and type selectors (but + to @vityata's) to get the href and navigate to that. QuerySelector returns first match which it appears will be the latest in your case

```
ie.Navigate2 .document.querySelector(".table-c a").href
```